# Obtener datos de select múltiple con serialize en PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, html-select

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un `select` múltiple:

```
<select multiple id='personal' name='personal' class='form-control'>
```

El tema es que al momento de realizar la función, la cual es *AJAX*, para obtener los datos del formulario con `.serialize()`, solo me recibe el último seleccionado del `select` y no todos.

Esta es mi función:

```
function recargarLista2(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"registroasistencia.php",
        data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
        success:function(r){
            $('#horas').html(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Por ejemplo, si los valores que selecciono son *1, 2, 3 y 4*, la idea sería que me tomara esos *4 valores* y en el otro *PHP* los extraigo creando un array, pero lo que sucede con el `.serialize()`, es que ***solo obtiene el cuarto valor, es decir el 4***.

Comment: ¿Funciona si le cambias el name al `select` por `name='personal[]'`?

Comment: Borro mi respuesta... Gracias @Marcos por recordarme mi falta de memoria T_T

Comment: @phpMyGuel, a todos nos pasa. Yo respondí y después pensé... que raro que esto no haya sido respondido antes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución simple es indicar que el `select` enviará un `array` de datos. Esto se consigue agregando corchetes al `name` del elemento. (`eg: name="personal[]"`).

Luego en `PHP` necesitas acceder a los datos iterando el `array`.

#### Ejemplo:

-- HTML

```
<select multiple id='personal' name='personal[]' class='form-control'>
  <option value="1" selected>Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Tres</option>
</select>
```

-- PHP (datos enviados por POST)

```
foreach($POST['personal'] as $valor) {
  echo $valor . "/n";
}
```